# Is there a QT4 equivalent of gksu, not dependent on KDE libraries?

Tags: sudo, qt

Is there a QT4 application with the same functionality as `sudo` to `gksu` that does not require an entire KDE desktop to be installed?

Comment: Good question, but weird use case.